# Timer-0 fatal Error

Tags: android, timer, android-asynctask

I am using timer to call WebService which will poll every 5 secs heres my code

```
timer=new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new MyWS().execute(URL);    
        }
    }, 1000, 5000);
```

But it is giving me FATAL Exception at MyWS().execute(URL); line. 
Following shows log cat

```
05-30 11:46:47.299: E/AndroidRuntime(2801): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
05-30 11:46:47.299: E/AndroidRuntime(2801): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
05-30 11:46:47.299: E/AndroidRuntime(2801):     at com.example.vuzixvideo.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:59)
05-30 11:46:47.299: E/AndroidRuntime(2801):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
05-30 11:46:47.299: E/AndroidRuntime(2801): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
05-30 11:46:47.299: E/AndroidRuntime(2801):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
05-30 11:46:47.299: E/AndroidRuntime(2801):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:607)
05-30 11:46:47.299: E/AndroidRuntime(2801):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:607)
05-30 11:46:47.299: E/AndroidRuntime(2801):     at android.os.AsyncTask.<clinit>(AsyncTask.java:190)
```

Comment: See **Threading Rules** @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html. Use a Service with alaram manager

Comment: @Raghunandan: So in order to use polling I need to use Handlers, But I tried, It is not polling

Comment: timertask runs on a different thread. you are supoosed to invoke asynctask on the ui thread. Read the link posted again. Also read about Handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action your executing in your timer must be trying to do something that needs to be happening on the main UI thread.  Try this:

```
timer=new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               new MyWS().execute(URL);   
           }
       });
   }
}, 1000, 5000);
```

or maybe this:

```
private Timer mTimer1;
private TimerTask mTt1;
private Handler mTimerHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

private void stopTimer(){
    if(mTimer1 != null){
        mTimer1.cancel();
        mTimer1.purge();
    }
}

private void startTimer(){
    mTimer1 = new Timer();
    mTt1 = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            mTimerHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run(){
                    new MyWS().execute(URL);   
                }
            });
        }
    };

    mTimer1.schedule(mTt1, 1, 5000);
}
```

This creates a handler on the main looper, and the timer will post actions to it.  I didn't test it out but it should work.

Comment: what is the use of timertask. Its runs in background then you use `runOnUiThread`.

Comment: also asynctask doinbackground runs on a background thread. i guess op needs a service

Comment: @bstar: THnx.. It really helped

Comment: @Rohit service is actually what you want. Timer + handler good luck

Comment: @Raghunandan: I know Timer+handler will drain my battery very fast also it will use my system resources, `AlarmManager` is a good option. But just I am carrying out some experiments